# Java Client application MQ channel closing issue (Queue manager runs out of resources)

Tags: java, websphere, message-queue, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Java CLient that connects to the Queue manager (MQQueuemanger ) on the server .
The queue manager runs out of resources after few runs of the application on the server. 
I get the following mail from the server admins,
"Your channel APP.CLIENT on CDT MQ Queue Manager AEDMXXX has been stopped. At the time it was stopped, 91 Active Channels were identified. We had to stop the channel before the Queue Manager AEDMXXX ran out of resources. This would have affected not just your application, but all other applications running on AEDMXXX. Please check your code and make sure you have closed EPS.CLIENT properly. Please create an admin ticket once you have done so, so that we can restart your channel APP.CLIENT. "

THis application was running fine in the Domino 7 server, but after the upgrade was done to Domino 8.5 the problem has started.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of default server channel connection, or decrease the bean size of the application which is connecting to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Presence of so many active channels indicate that your client application is not closing connections to queue manager. Check your code to see if connections are being closed properly after job is done. If there is connection pooling in Domino 8.5, check the configuration of connection pooling to see if a new connection is being created instead of reusing available connection.

Increasing MaxActiveChannels will only postpone in the issue. It's better to identify the reason and fix it.